# REGEX formulating conditions

Tags: python, regex

Just started learning python and regex.

```
My regex:
\b\d+\s+([A-Za-z]* |[A-Za-z]*\s+[A-Za-z]*)\s+\D+..
```

using https://regex101.com/

**string 1:** https://i.imgur.com/XNuXftW.jpg (why does Beer has whitespaces while carrot/chocolate dont have?)

**string 2**https://i.imgur.com/nrl2FPB.jpg  (adding further more of \s+[A-Za-z] in the capture group doesnt seem to be working anymore, WHY?)

**string 3**: https://i.imgur.com/qH0Z7Hi.jpg (same as string 2 problem)

my question is how do i continue to formulate such that it will encompass the above conditions? thank you

in the case that you need to test it yourself, i have provided the strings as below.

=

Comment: You did not mention what your expected output is. A list of products?

Comment: YES it is! if possible a list of product with , after printing

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\d+\s+([A-Za-z ]*)\b *\D+
```

See on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rlFheb/2).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex, which takes advantage of look-behind (`?<=`) and look-ahead `(?=`) so it only captures the product names:

```
(?<=\s\s)\w+(?:\s\w+)*(?=\s\s)
```

See demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rtIXLK/2).

Use it with the `g` modifier.

Comment: SWEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEET! LOVE YA

Answer (score 1):

I guess the the space before "|" is the one causes it captures "beer " in **string 1 case** "Chocolate cake" does not happen as "beer " as it is matched with the second regex which is

```
[A-Za-z]*\s+[A-Za-z]*
```

for **string 2** 
    [A-Za-z]*\s+[A-Za-z]*
regex matches exactly two words

How about try below regex, modified from trincot

```
(?<=\s\s)(\w+\s)+(\w+)(?=\s\s)
```

Comment: Your modification on my answer degrades it: it will always select an extra space at the end of the product name.

Comment: Edited! Thank for reminding. After all I think yours regex is better than mine